# aws sam package - unable to upload artifact, access denied when doing 'package' locally but the S3 bucket exists and I have access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I try to package but I get:

```
$ sam package --s3-bucket sam-project-deployment--29 --output-template-file output.yaml --region us-east-2
Error: Unable to upload artifact HelloWorldFunction  
referenced by CodeUri parameter of HelloWorldFunction resource.
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

Answer (score 3):

The  problem in my case was that I had switched computers and not realized that my aws cli was still logged into another account.

I fixed this by doing

```
aws configure
```

and using the id and access key for the correct account.

Comment: exactly the same problem with me, but I had changed accounts and not computers.